# ¿Como poner identacion de 2 espacios en sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

Hola quiero que en lugar de los 4 espacios que sublime text 3 me hace en la indentación al hacer tab sean solo dos espacios ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En el menú vas a View > Indentation > Tab width: 2 .

Comment: Genial muchas gracias

Answer (score 4):

Otra forma de hacerlo es usando [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/) para que sea independiente al editor.

Para poder usarlo solo necesitas crear un `.editorconfig` dentro de tu proyecto, agregarle las opciones que deseas y por último instalar el [plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/EditorConfig) para reconocer las configuraciones. Ejemplo de un `.editorconfig`:

```
style_guide_version = 1.1.0

# editorconfig.org
root = true

indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
max_line_length = 120
```

Comment: Intentare esto gracias

Comment: Hola @IsraelOmarDelAngelValencia si esta o cualquier otra respuesta ha resuelto su problema, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) clicando la marca de check (en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto indica a la comunidad que has encontrado una solución y de paso os dará reputación a ambos (a tí y quien ha respondido). Por supuesto, no tienes ninguna obligación de hacerlo.